# How do I install a tools package with no internet or USB?

Tags: package-management, compiling

This is a build environment for custom hardware (NXP processor). There is Ethernet access only. Build/deploy sequence is:

1. log in to dev server
2. bring up docker to build under Ubuntu 20.04 (using flex_builder)
3. run build
4. exit docker
5. SCP build to custom hardware for test

Custom package (under test) does not have gcc or enough memory to run it on the target HW, and the docker container cannot run the built image. The tool in question has not been included in the base build.

I have the source in [build head]/components/linux/linux/tools/spi as spidev_fdx.c, along with the make and Build file.

Question is - what do I configure (and how) to get this tool built and included in the rest of the package?

Thanks